# Kendo UI Splitter height

Tags: kendo-ui, splitter

Posted 3 hours ago (permalink)

Hi everyone,

I'm doing an ASP.NET MVC project with Kendo UI, and I've got a little problem.

I have a jquery script for re sizing my splitter.

```
window.onload = function () {
      $("#vertical").css("height", $(window).height());
};
```

But when I load my layout, I've got the good size, but not the good display.

If I hide my bottom splitter , and then show it, it's the well display (2.png)
Thanks all for you answers :)

Comment: Hi everyone, if you still have the issue, try :

$("#vertical").data("kendoSplitter").trigger("resize");

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following css #vertical{height:100%;} ?